# How to install Python4Delphi?

Tags: python, delphi

I am using Delphi CE 10.4.
I want to use Python4Delphi.
The settings for MultiInstaller is

```
[Package - Python4Delphi]
Name=Python4Delphi
Folder=P4D
SearchPath="Source"
LibSuffix=%s0
D27="Packages\Delphi\Delphi 10.4+\Python.dpk", "Packages\Delphi\Delphi 10.4+\dclPython.dpk"
D28="Packages\Delphi\Delphi 10.4+\Python.dpk", "Packages\Delphi\Delphi 10.4+\dclPython.dpk"
```

Should the Folder be="..\P4D" because the files are in the parent folder?

The error is "
Error: E:\PythonFiles\P4D\python4delphi\Install\ doesn't exist."
Can anyone show me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always install it manually just as any other package. Open the project group `"Python4Delphi\Packages\Delphi\Delphi 10.4+\P4DComponentSuite.groupproj"`, find three dcl's, click compile them and install:

[image: like this]

Then go to `Tools-Options-Language-Delphi-Library` and tell the IDE where to find the sources. You should modify the "Library Path" and the "Browsing path". Add 3 folders: source, source/vlc and source/fmx, as shown on the screenshot. Repeat it for both Windows 32 and Windows 64 platforms.

[image: like this]

Also there is a [video instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjY6lBgrHhM)